# Matplotlib - Clustered Bar Chart from Dict with multiple values per key

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given dict.items() look something like this:

```
('a', [11, 10])
('b', [10, 11])
('c', [7, 6])
('d', [5, 5])
('e', [21])
```

First, how could I append a second value to 'e' so the length matches the others?

Second, ignoring the length issue with e, how could I do a clustered bar chart of the values with the key for the label.

Seems like I'd want to break the values into lists and plot

```
ax.bar(len(d.keys()), list1, width='0.5', color='r')
ax.bar(len(d.keys()), list2, width='0.5', color='r')
```

I've never had to plot a dict with multiple values per key before and I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can append `new_value` to `d['e']` with

```
d['e'].append(new_value)
```

Logical when you think about it. The individual value lists can be obtained with

```
list1 = [x[0] for x in d.values()]
list2 = [x[1] for x in d.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = dict([('a', [11, 10]), ('b', [10, 11]),
             ('c', [7, 6]), ('d', [5, 5]),
             ('e', [21])])
```

holdenweb's answer is good for appending to a dict entry:

```
# add to e
new_value = 22
data['e'].append(new_value)
```

Now convert to a Pandas data frame, and `plot()`:

```
# convert to data frame 
# .T transposes letter categories to the x-axis
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T

# plot grouped bar chart
df.plot(kind="bar")
```

[image: bar plot]